# How do I remove the theta grid and radius grid on a polar plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I was trying to plot spiral of the Archimedes:

```
t = linspace(0,5*pi,1000);
a =1;
r = a.*t;
polar(t,r);
grid off;
Ax = gca; 
Ax.ThetaGrid = 'off';
Ax.RGrid = 'off';
Ax.RTickLabel = []; 
Ax.ThetaTickLabel = [];
```

However, the following error is shown:

```
Unrecognized property 'ThetaGrid' for class 'matlab.graphics.axis.Axes'.
```

How do I remove the grids and labels on this image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = linspace(0,5*pi,1000);
a =1;
r = a.*t;
line_handle = polarplot(t,r); % Get line handle
Ax = line_handle.Parent; % Get its parent, i.e. polar axes
grid off;
Ax.ThetaGrid = 'off';
Ax.RGrid = 'off';
Ax.RTickLabel = [];
Ax.ThetaTickLabel = [];
```

generates

[image]

The problem is that first doing `grid off` somehow changes what the current axes are, setting them back to Cartesian. As a Cartesian axes object does not have polar coordinates defined, you get the error.
Instead, grab a handle on the line, then grab its `Parent`, your polar-axes object. That has all the properties you want to change.

*PS, MATLAB warned me to use [`polarplot`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html) rather than [`polar`](https://mathworks.com/help/rf/ug/polar.html), so I did.*